# Accessing method of stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a stateful widget class, TextFieldMakerClass, that creates some text fields with functions. In this widget, I've got a method, `clearAll()`, that resets the text fields and so on. The method is in the _TextFieldMakerClass extends State part of the stateful widget.

I'm calling TextFieldMakerClass() from the class (ScaffoldClass) that's got the Scaffold, and want a button that resets the text fields (this is to be done by calling the method `clearAll()`). I've created an instance variable in my ScaffoldClass:

TextFieldMakerClass textFieldMakerClass = TextFieldMakerClass();

That I call in the Scaffold, and this works fine, but I cannot reach the `clearAll()` method from this object when I try `textFieldMakerClass.clearAll()` Flutter tells me: "the method `clearAll` isn't defined for the class TextFieldMakerClass.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Upload your code so I can help where needed @LegendWK

Comment: TextFieldMakerClass: https://codeshare.io/G8xbm4

Comment: ScaffoldClass: https://codeshare.io/alr0Pm, @RandomGuru

Comment: The GlobalKey fetches the data of the FextFields, but I want to reset and remove them using the method. Isn't there an easy way to access the method from my other class?